# How do nodes (and objects) actually work when assigned to each other

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to understand how Linked Lists work in Java but I'm confused as to Java keeps track of head.next(see code example).

Node class(nested) and constructor:

```
private static class Node<T>{
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;
    private Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Method:

```
void test(T item, T item2, T item3){
    Node<T> n = new Node<T>(item);
    Node<T> n2 = new Node<T>(item2);
    Node<T> n3 = new Node<T>(item3);
    tail = n;
    head = tail;
    tail.next = n2;
    System.out.println("head.next.data = " + head.next.data);
    System.out.println("tail.next.data = " + tail.next.data);
    tail = n2;
    tail.next = n3;
    System.out.println("head.next.data = " + head.next.data);
    System.out.println("tail.next.data = " + tail.next.data);
}
```

Assuming item is 2, item2 is 3, and item3 is 4, this gives the following print results:

```
head.next.data = 3
tail.next.data = 3
head.next.data = 3
tail.next.data = 4
```

Why is head.next.data set to 3 when it wasn't initialized, and why does it remain 3 even after tail is changed?

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
tail = n;
```

which means `tail` points to `n`.

```
head = tail;
```

Since both now point to `n`, and given you set tail's next to `n` hence you see `head.next` as 3.

Comment: So if I add more nodes to the linked list and keep pointing tail towards each new node n (but do not set head = tail anymore), why is it that if I make multiple calls to head = head.next, I'll get all the values that tail.next have been before?